# What is best python module to find latitude and longitude?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am working on a calendar like project using django framework, while creating an event we will store the event address and based on the address we need to find latitude and longitude and also should be able to filter those events based on the address entered. Please tell me which module is best used.

For example if we give either state, city, province, zipcode it should return latitude and longitude.

Comment: quick google search I found this python wrapper for google maps,

http://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/

Answer (score 0):

Hostip.info is an open-source project with the goal to build/maintain a database mapping IP addresses to cities. Their about page explains the data sources relied on to populate this database.
http://www.hostip.info/

Using HostIP, there are two ways to get location data from an IP address:

They also have a well-designed and easy-to-use RESTFUL API: just pass in your ip address after the i*p=* in the GET request string):

```
import urllib

response = urllib.urlopen('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19&position=true').read()

print(response)
```

Second, the Project Website also makes its complete database available for download.
http://www.hostip.info/dl/index.html